# Is Exchange 2010 compliant with RFC 3848

Tags: smtp, exchange-server, exchange-server-2010, email-headers, smtp-auth

I have looked up

[Exchange 2010 Support for RFC Standards](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff848256%28v=exchg.141%29.aspx)

but do not see **RFC 3848** amongst the supported standards.  I do see RFC 4954 listed, which 'recommends use of RFC 3848 transmission types', though I cannot tell if this means any mail server compliant with 4954 *must* also be compliant with 3848.

Specifically, I am trying to find out whether Exchange is capable of adding 'ESMTPA' or 'ESMTPSA' extensions to email headers to indicate SMTP authentication.  It would seem peculiar if Exchange did not support this standard...

Thank you.